# ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence Ask

Tags: least-squares, model-fitting

This python code:

```
import numpy,math
import scipy.optimize as optimization
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt    
# Create toy data for curve_fit.
zo = numpy.array([0.0,1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0,5.0])
mu = numpy.array([0.1,0.9,2.2,2.8,3.9,5.1])
sig = numpy.array([1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0])
# Define hubble function.
def Hubble(x,a,b):
    return H0 * m.sqrt( a*(1+x)**2 + 1/2 * a * (1+b)**3 )

# Define 
def Distancez(x,a,b):
    return c * (1+x)* np.asarray(quad(lambda tmp: 
1/Hubble(a,b,tmp),0,x))
def mag(x,a,b):
    return 5*np.log10(Distancez(x,a,b)) + 25
    #return a+b*x

# Compute chi-square manifold.
Steps = 101  # grid size
Chi2Manifold = numpy.zeros([Steps,Steps])  # allocate grid
amin = 0.2  # minimal value of a covered by grid
amax = 0.3  # maximal value of a covered by grid
bmin = 0.3  # minimal value of b covered by grid
bmax = 0.6  # maximal value of b covered by grid
for s1 in range(Steps):
    for s2 in range(Steps):
        # Current values of (a,b) at grid position (s1,s2).
        a = amin + (amax - amin)*float(s1)/(Steps-1)
        b = bmin + (bmax - bmin)*float(s2)/(Steps-1)
        # Evaluate chi-squared.
        chi2 = 0.0
        for n in range(len(xdata)):
            residual = (mu[n] - mag(zo[n], a, b))/sig[n]
            chi2 = chi2 + residual*residual
        Chi2Manifold[Steps-1-s2,s1] = chi2  # write result to grid.
```

Throws this error message:

```
ValueError Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-136-d0ef47a881a7> in <module>()
     36             residual = (mu[n] - mag(zo[n], a, b))/sig[n]
     37             chi2 = chi2 + residual*residual
---> 38         Chi2Manifold[Steps-1-s2,s1] = chi2  # write result to 
grid.

ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

Note: If I define a simple mag function such as (a+b*x), I do not get any error message.

---

In fact all three functions Hubble, Distancez and Meg have to be functions of redshift z, which is an array.

Now do you think I need to redefine all these functions to have an output array? I mean first, create an array of redshift and then the output of the functions automatically become array?

---

I need the output of the Distancez() and mag() functions to be arrays. I managed to do it, simply by changing the upper limit of the integral in the Distancez function from x to x.any(). Now I have an array and this is what I want. However, now I see that the output value of the for example Distance(0.25, 0.5, 0.3) is different from when I just put x in the upper limit of the integral? Any help would be appreciated.

---

Thanks for your reply.

I need the output of the Distancez() and mag() functions to be arrays. I managed to do it, simply by changing the upper limit of the integral in the Distancez  function from x to x.any(). Now I have an array and this is what I want. However, now I see that the output value of the for example Distance(0.25, 0.5, 0.3) is different from when I just put x in the upper limit of the integral? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The ValueError is saying that it cannot assign an element of the array `Chi2Manifold` with a value that is a sequence.  `chi2` is probably a numpy array because `residual` is a numpy array because, your `mag()` function returns a numpy array, all because your `Distancez` function returns an numpy array -- you are telling it to do this with that `np.asarray()`.

If `Distancez()` returned a scalar floating point value you'd probably be set.  Do you need to use `np.asarray()` in `Distancez()`?   Is that actually a 1-element array, or perhaps you intend to reduce that somehow to a scalar.  I don't know what your `Hubble()` function is supposed to do and I'm not an astronomer but in my experience distances are often scalars ;).

If `chi2` is meant to be a sequence  or numpy array, you probably want to set an appropriately-sized range of values in `Chi2Manifold` to `chi2`.